# R scatter plot fills the entire plot area

Tags: r, statistics, visualization, scatter-plot

New to R, I'm trying it out on a data set scraped from a Marathon results site and encountered the following problem while making an x-y scatter plot on the durations of each 5km lap and those of the following lap.

Specifically:

- The **30km-35km plot (sixth graph below) shows complete darkness** while others seem okay.
- The **default labels on the x and y axes behave strangely**, i.e. some are showing column names, some are not showing, and the 'all-filled' plot shows "x" and "y", rather than column names.

I would appreciate it if you could help me understand what really happened.

I'm completely new to Statistics and R, so any hint or comment is highly appreciated.

Here's the plot in question:

[image: Lap-wise scatter plots.]

The R script for the above is reproduced here:

```
CreateLapPlots <- function(){
  par(mfrow=c(2,4))
  plot(male$X5km_lap_secs, male$X10km_lap_secs)
  plot(male$X10km_lap_secs, male$X15km_lap_secs)
  plot(male$X15km_lap_secs, male$X20km_lap_secs)
  plot(male$X20km_lap_secs, male$X25km_lap_secs)
  plot(male$X25km_lap_secs, male$X30km_lap_secs)
  plot(male$X30km_lap_secs, male$X35km_lap_secs)
  plot(male$X35km_lap_secs, male$X40km_lap_secs)
}
```

And the male object has the following columns (please excuse my misuse of terminology):

```
[1] "bib"               "name"              "gender"            "X5km_split"        "X5km_split_secs"   "X5km_net"         
[7] "X5km_net_secs"     "X5km_lap"          "X5km_lap_secs"     "X5km_time"         "X10km_split"       "X10km_split_secs" 
[13] "X10km_net"         "X10km_net_secs"    "X10km_lap"         "X10km_lap_secs"    "X10km_time"        "X15km_split"      
[19] "X15km_split_secs"  "X15km_net"         "X15km_net_secs"    "X15km_lap"         "X15km_lap_secs"    "X15km_time"       
[25] "X20km_split"       "X20km_split_secs"  "X20km_net"         "X20km_net_secs"    "X20km_lap"         "X20km_lap_secs"   
[31] "X20km_time"        "X25km_split"       "X25km_split_secs"  "X25km_net"         "X25km_net_secs"    "X25km_lap"        
[37] "X25km_lap_secs"    "X25km_time"        "X30km_split"       "X30km_split_secs"  "X30km_net"         "X30km_net_secs"   
[43] "X30km_lap"         "X30km_lap_secs"    "X30km_time"        "X35km_split"       "X35km_split_secs"  "X35km_net"        
[49] "X35km_net_secs"    "X35km_lap"         "X35km_lap_secs"    "X35km_time"        "X40km_split"       "X40km_split_secs" 
[55] "X40km_net"         "X40km_net_secs"    "X40km_lap"         "X40km_lap_secs"    "X40km_time"        "Finish_split"     
[61] "Finish_split_secs" "Finish_net"        "Finish_net_secs"   "Finish_lap"        "Finish_lap_secs"   "Finish_time"
```

The raw data and the R scripts are available here if you need them: https://github.com/hktang/rscraper

Comment: your columns are factors, try `idx <- grep('lap_secs', names(male)); male[, idx] <- lapply(male[, idx], as.numeric)` and next time make your question minimal and reproducible. you're asking us for help so we shouldnt have to go download your 21mb file and look around your repo for the 8 lines of relevant code to answer your question

Comment: @rawr Thank you for the advice and hint, both of which are very helpful. I will read more about factors and the functions you provided. I've also updated the question with the hope that it helps with readability.